# performFetchWithCompletionHandler after reboot?

Tags: ios, background

I am fairly certain that performFetchWithCompletionHandler was called for my app after a reboot of the device, without having to open the app when that was introduced with iOS 7.

However, right now with my sample app, it does not seem to get called when my phone is rebooted, neither on iOS 7 / Xcode 5 nor iOS 8 / Xcode 6 or 5

Can anyone point me to definite documentation on that subject?

I will update this question with a sample app soon

Comment: What is your `minimumBackgroundFetchInterval` ?

Comment: I have set it to five minutes, but waited much longer than that. Will set it to UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum and try again …